# parse email and append google sheets

Tags: regex, parsing, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I'm trying to extract information sent to me on a regular basis from messages in g-mail. I would like to extract data from the emails and have it added to a spreadsheet within google sheets.

I have absolutely no experience with this type of programming and I have been using trial and error to try and figure this out. I have had no luck so far and all I can get is for the spreadsheet to get the null value written on it.

I am trying to use regular expressions to parse the data I need and then from there I am using appendRow to write to the spreadsheet.

```
function processInboxToSheet() {

var start = 0;
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start, 100);
var SPREADSHEET_URL =    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18TzTzylbmu-g2lQyZo-YoscxW8SIK7a-tg/edit?usp=sharing";
var SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet1';
var result = [];


var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
var qs_sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

var content = messages[0].getRawContent();

if (content) {
```

I think my problem lies here:

```
  var tmp;
  var stringToParse = "*Longitude* W119.37938";
  tmp = stringToParse.match(/d{1,4}\.\d{5}/);
  var username = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No username';



  qs_sheet.appendRow([username]);

  Utilities.sleep(500);
 }
 }
 };
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's missing a backslash: `d{1,4}` --> `\d{1,4}`

Comment: You have not specified any capture groups in your regex, and are using `tmp[1]`. If you need the `119.37938` value, just use `tmp[0]`. And Mariano is right, you need to use a `\d` to match a digit. Have a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yb95z930/).

Answer (score 0):

Beside the typo in your regex (missing backslash with the first `d`), the problem is that you have not specified any capture groups in your regex (round-bracketed groups), and are trying to access the first non-existing capture group with `tmp[1]`.

If you need to get the `119.37938` value, just use `tmp[0]`:

```js
var stringToParse = "*Longitude* W119.37938";
tmp = stringToParse.match(/\d{1,4}\.\d{5}/);
var username = (tmp && tmp[0]) ? tmp[0] : 'No username';
document.write(username);
```

Note that `.trim()` is redundant since your regex only captures digits at the end of the match.